# How can I create two priority queues containing same class of object but sort them in different attributes of the object class?

Tags: java, oop, object, priority-queue

I am stuck on designing my priority queues.

I have an implemented class

```
public class MyObject{
    private int attribute_1;
    private String attribute_2;
    ... 
}
```

I would like to have two priority queues that one sort `MyObject` by `attribute_1` and the other sort `attribute_2`.

How can I realize that?

Comment: java.util.PriorityQueue? Provide two different comparators to two queues.

Comment: @bayou.io So I need to extend the two different priority queue from `java.util.PriorityQueue` and make two different classes?

Comment: call `new PriorityQueue<>(capacity, comparator)` where the comparator compares `attr_1` or `attr_2`

Comment: @JiajuShen That's probably overkill - just use one of the overloads that accepts a `Comparator` and encapsulate the sorting logic in a comparator.

Comment: @bayou.io What if I do not know the possible capacity of the priority queue? The content in the priority queue are from external input.

Comment: use 42:) it's just the initial capacity, it doesn't matter.